# How can I add space between anchor tags?

Tags: html, css, anchor

I want to give my anchor tags some elbow room. I tried to add both padding and margin, and neither one work (even when I give them a *lot*, as you can see here):

```
a {
    line-height: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 120;
    margin: 42;
}
```

How can I add some spacing between the anchor elements?

The entire kit and kaboodle are here: http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/pRgQL/

I ended up going with this: http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/pRgQL/18/

Comment: [By using units](http://jsfiddle.net/pRgQL/3/).

Comment: Removed the jsFiddle tag because it states: `Do not use this tag to indicate that your question contains a jsFiddle example`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In CSS the different lengths/sizes need to have specific units, the browser doesn't guess your intent, it simply discards invalid property values, in this case I used `px`, since I'm assuming that's what you wanted to use:

```
a {
    line-height: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 120px;
    margin: 42px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pRgQL/7/).

Alternative units *include* (but are not limited to): `em`, `rem`, `ex`, `pt`, `cm` (among others).

References:

- [CSS Values and Units Module, Distance Units: the `<length>` type](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths).

Comment: Somethings don't need units. Line height is a great place not to use units.

Answer (score 17):

```
<a>1<a/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a>2<a/>
```

1    2

non breaking space if you like ..

Comment: So you don't like, everyone is entitled to an opinion. Sometimes simple is as simple is.

Comment: No way man, its only a space (inline without header and footer padding). Don't throw out the tools in your box because they are not fashionable.

Comment: There's something called CSS that does the job for you.

Comment: Maybe I only want to space a single instance, not the whole class. I'm only making the suggestion, you are being obtuse.

Comment: I was talking in relevance to this specific problem of the Q. Either way, your hack is hack, but obviously not good practice, just saying.

Comment: Add value, tell us how to inline space without adding header and footer space. Which CSS property and which unit.

Comment: Perhaps `&emsp;` would better fit your needs here. It gives a 1em width space, instead of the smaller space provided by `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the units to your margin and padding e.g.

```
padding: 120px;
margin: 42px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sir, I may add, that you forgot to add units to your numbers. The numbers must have units, so please try adding `px`. That should do the magic for you. For example:

```
a {
    line-height: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 120px;
    margin: 42px;
}
```